# Not able to generate Signature For AWS Signature Version 4 in Javascript Angular 8

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, angular8, aws-sdk-js

1. This is my service in angular 8. For Generating the Header for HTTP Method. It gives me the Error for Signature not getting matched with the signature that I have generated.
   With

accessKeyId: "AKIA*******UTIZO5UUP",
secretAccessKey: "n5bndDO***************xb3IA0GvmAVTOaDLNDG"

```
execute(credentials, request) {
    let url = new URL(request.url);
    let date = new Date();
    credentials.host = url.host;
    request.route = url.pathname;

    let canonical = this.canonicalRequest(credentials, request, date);
    console.log("canonical: ", canonical);
    let toSign = this.requestToSign(canonical, credentials, date);
    console.log("toSign: ", toSign);
    let signature = this.signature(toSign, credentials, date);
    console.log("signature: ", signature);

    return {
      "x-amz-date": this.amzLongDate(date),
      Authorization:
        "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=" +
        credentials.accessKeyId +
        "/" +
        this.amzShortDate(date) +
        "/" +
        credentials.region +
        "/execute-api/aws4_request, " +
        ("SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date" +
          (credentials.token ? "x-amz-security-token" : "") +
          ", Signature=" +
          signature),
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "x-amz-security-token": credentials.token || undefined
      // host: this.credentials.host,
    };
  }

  canonicalRequest(credentials, request, date) {
    return (
      "\n" +
      this.request.method.toUpperCase() +
      "\n" +
      (request.route.charAt(0) !== "/" ? "/" + request.route : request.route) + //
      "\n" +
      this.queryParameters(request.query) +
      "\ncontent-type:application/json\nhost:" +
      credentials.host +
      "\n" +
      ("x-amz-date:" +
        this.amzLongDate(date) +
        "\n" +
        (credentials.token
          ? "x-amz-security-token:" + credentials.token + "\n"
          : "") +
        "\n") +
      ("content-type;host;x-amz-date" +
        (credentials.token ? ";x-amz-security-token" : "") +
        "\n") +
      this.hashString(this.request.body)
    );
  }

  requestToSign(cRequest, credentials, date) {
    return (
      "\n" +
      "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n" +
      this.amzLongDate(date) +
      "\n" +
      this.amzShortDate(date) +
      "/" +
      credentials.region +
      "/execute-api/aws4_request\n" +
      this.hashString(cRequest)
    );
  }

  signature(toSign, credentials, date) {
    return this.hmac(
      this.hmac(
        this.hmac(
          this.hmac(
            this.hmac(
              "AWS4" + credentials.secretAccessKey,
              this.amzShortDate(date)
            ),
            credentials.region
          ),
          "execute-api"
        ),
        "aws4_request"
      ),
      toSign
    ).toString();
  }

  queryParameters(queryParameterObj) {
    var pieces = [];
    if (queryParameterObj) {
      Object.keys(queryParameterObj)
        .sort()
        .forEach(function(k) {
          return pieces.push(
            k + "=" + encodeURIComponent(queryParameterObj[k])
          );
        });
    }
    return pieces.length > 0 ? pieces.join("&") : "";
  }

  hashString(str) {
    return CryptoJS.SHA256(str).toString();
  }

  hmac(key, value) {
    return CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(value, key);
  }

  amzShortDate(date) {
    return this.amzLongDate(date).substr(0, 8);
  }

  amzLongDate(date) {
    return date
      .toISOString()
      .replace(/[:\-]|\.\d{3}/g, "")
      .substr(0, 17);
  }
```

2. Then This is my Object For the Method to generate them by which I would Call execute method

```
credentials = {
    region: "us-east-1",
    accessKeyId: "AKIA*******UTIZO5UUP",
    secretAccessKey: "n5bndDO***************xb3IA0GvmAVTOaDLNDG",
    host: "",
    token: null
  };
  request = {
    url:
      "https://jml******xa.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/name-of-app/review/v1",
    type: "GET",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: { foo: "bar" },
    route: "",
    query: null,
    body: null
  };
```

3. The isuues is I am able to get the correct canonicalRequest and requestToSign but the signature is not getting matched as it says....

```
{
    "message": "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.\n\nThe Canonical String for this request should have been\n'GET\n/name-of-app/review/v1\n\ncontent-type:application/json\nhost:jq******xa.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\nx-amz-date:20200227T162638Z\n\ncontent-type;host;x-amz-date\ne3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855'\n\nThe String-to-Sign should have been\n'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20200227T162638Z\n20200227/us-east-1/execute-api/aws4_request\n9f4671025ee537c0253df73dc1c673d30e22966b3ac544f03df14e3b85f76238'\n"
}
```

Comment: Did you ever solved this?